# Iterate through all rows, convert timestamp stored in database to UTC version and update it back

Tags: postgresql

I have postgres database table, in that I have stored timestamps which are actually "Australia/Melbourne" timezone version of timestamps, and I want to update those to "UTC" version. How can I do that in one single postgres function?

I have looked for functions as I think we can iterate through rows in table and execute update in for loops. I know the single query using which you can get and update only one record at a time:

```
SELECT timestamp_column AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Melbourne' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
from my_schema.my_table;`
```

Current table:

```
timestamp
---------------
2018-08-27 16:15:25.348
2018-05-15 13:52:12.052
2018-05-15 14:28:58.239
...
...
```

Expected  table:

```
timestamp
----------------
2018-08-27 06:15:25.348
2018-05-15 03:52:12.052
2018-05-15 04:28:58.239
...
...
```

Comment: `update my_table set column = column at time zone ...`?

Comment: Yupe, But it only update one record at time

Comment: No, if you leave the `where` clause of the `update` suitably non-specific, it'll update multiple rows - possibly the whole table. In SQL, we look to write *set-based* code, *not* loops or iteration.

Comment: without a `where` clause it will update all rows in the table

Comment: Holy moly, its seems working, I havent thought of that because I was kind of preparing batch jobs for all my tables which have similar issues and also didnt aware about timezone converstations. Thanks....